# extract audio file metadata without uploading in nodejs with fileStream

Tags: node.js, audio, metadata, filestream

I am trying to add a feature to my node.js web app so that when the user inputs multiple audio files, I can extract and display metadata info for each file like the title/artist/album/year etc. I'm trying to add this so that it works for most audio files (mp3/wav/flac/etc..) ideally as many audio types as possible.

This example (with a github link) shows its possible: https://audio-tag-analyzer.netlify.app/ doing pretty much exactly what I want. The code for this site is a react app however which im not familiar with.

I've looked into a couple different possible solutions for accomplishing my goal inside my node.js web app:

- option1: use default file input selection

Wont work because file defauly file input selection returns a FileList object that only has name/size/type info (no metadata)
[image]

- option2: use music-metadata npm package to read file using parseFile

Using this package: https://github.com/Borewit/music-metadata you can use the parseFile input option if you have the full filepath, I cant get this in the browser without uploading the file to my local server which id like to avoid

- option3: Using Node.js streams using the parseStream function.

Using this package: https://github.com/Borewit/music-metadata

the parseStream example code for this package needs 'someReadStream' as an input like so:

```
mm.parseStream(someReadStream, {mimeType: 'audio/mpeg', size: 26838})
  .then( metadata => {
     console.log(util.inspect(metadata, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
     someReadStream.destroy();
   });
```

I've been looking into this solution but haven't been able to get it working yet, im reading file inputs through this html code:

```
 <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

Should I be watching for the event when the files are inputted, then create a readFileStream on the frontend somehow, and then pass that readFileStream to my backend so I can run the package to extract metadata info?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different library since that one doesn't seem to have a front end that doesn't require react, angular or some other tools like browserify to make it work. Note: I tried to make it work with browserify but ran into a bunch of issues with it. I spent way too much time trying to make that one work for fun lolz.

Anyways, here is a good way to get all the tags using `jsmediatags`

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  function readSong(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      window.jsmediatags.read(file, {
          onSuccess: (tag) => {
            resolve(tag.tags);
          },
          onError: (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
      });
    });
  }

  $("#file").change(async (event) => {
    var fileList = event.target.files;
    try {
      const tags = await readSong(fileList[0]);
      console.log(tags);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsmediatags/3.9.3/jsmediatags.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./lib/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, this solution works very well for mp3 files, but not for flac audio files. There's probably a front end solution for flac as well, but I'm trying not to have specific code for each fileType, something like `if(type=mp3){ use this }else if(type=flac){ use this }...`

Comment: @Martin sometimes one tool can't fit them all. I would say browserifying this music-metadata lib was starting to look like a hack because of the way one needs to export the lib for it to work properly. Rather than hacking current libs, its probs best to choose the right tools for the job. Meaning, work on react and use the libraries that you want to use, or try to find libs that provide vanilla frontend javascript support. For your case, since react is not an option, i would go the above way you mentioned of writing code depending on files.